# Почему не работает луп?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день, в постоянных ссылках стоит вывод /%category%/%postname%/

В ардесной строке браузера отображается [http://localhost/categroy/основная-категория/дочерняя-категория/пост](http://localhost/categroy/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82)

Есил я перехожу по ссылкам категорий все хорошо, если я в основной категории выводятся все посты данной категории, если я проваливаюсь в подкатегорию я вижу все посты подкатегории, но когда я убираю из url category через functions.php

```
// Remove category from url
    add_filter('category_link', create_function('$a', 'return str_replace("category/", "", $a);'), 9999);
```

либо через .htaccess либо точкой без разницы, почему-то перестают выводится посты подкатегории если я проваливаюсь в подкатегории, но когда я проваливаюсь в категории он работает и выводит список постов данной категории. Шаблон index.php использую, там все просто, `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

Если возвращаю назад category в url все работает.

Comment: Игры с ЧПУ чреваты нехорошими последствиями. Но если очень хочется убрать `category` из урла, то есть готовый плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/

Comment: @SeVlad Спасибо, помог плагин все работет.